# Question about using PointCloud2 as sensor msg input to costmap2d

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just wondering how to use PointCloud2 as the input sensor msg instead of Laserscan into costmap? Any help will be appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45195/question-about-using-pointcloud2-as-sensor-msg-input-to-costmap2d/) by [richard](https://answers.ros.org/users/3324/richard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a Pointcloud_to_Laserscan package, which works fine.

If I remind correctly, you have to make your own launchfile - if you need help on that,
I can search for my launchfile(I basically did the same).

Just for information: The package will take your PointCloud and generate a LaserScan from it.

---

Originally posted by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) with karma: 342 on 2012-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0